# React router: save an extended path as a route param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to have a path that looks like this:

```
/projects/:projectId/:folder1/:folder2/.../:folderN/:currentFolder/
```

Where `projectId` will be a single string like `1`, and `folder1, folder2, ..., folderN` come from splitting the path at that location.

So a regex like this would match it completely fine:

```
/\/?projects\/(\w|\d)+\/folders\/((\w|\d)*\/?)*(\w|\d)+\/?/;
```

However, I am having trouble saving the path of folders that precede the current folder as a parameter in the routes. That is to say, I can get something like `:projectId` and `:currentFolder`, but I want to save the list of folders leading up to current folder as `:path` or something.

What is the syntax for saving this arbitrary path in react router?

Answer (score 1):

Params only match [URL segments](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/modules/PatternUtils.js#L65-L66).

For an indeterminate number of folders, there is no practical way of doing this with params except for having `N` routes (where `N` is a known maximum number of possible folders). Doing that of course would be tedious and would break if `N` were to ever increase without the addition of even more routes.

Your best bet would be to use a wildcard operator to match all of the folders and then do a string split on the `params.splat` value wherever you need to access the folders.

```
<Route path=":productId/**/:currentFolder" component={Folder} />
```

Given the pathname: `/17/this/is/the/path/to/the/folder`

```
const Folder = ({ params }) => {
  const { productId, splat, currentFolder } = params
  const folders = splat.split('/')
  // productId = '17'
  // currentFolder = 'folder'
  // folders = ['this', 'is', 'the', 'path', 'to', 'the']
  ...
}
```

Comment: For which version of react-router? I am not getting `splat` in my route params

Comment: That was for 2/3. Are you using 4?

Comment: I am on version 3.0.0

Comment: Hmm, the version I tested this on was 3. Can you `console.log(pattern, paramNames)` after this line in the React Router source? https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/modules/PatternUtils.js#L86 (edit the file in the `node_modules` folder).